# How do I finish finding the volume of this solid torus?

Tags: calculus

> Use cylindrical shells to find the volume $V$ of the solid torus (the donut-shaped solid shown in the figure) with radii $r$ and $R$.
>
> [image]

This is as far I have come. How can I solve further?

[image]

Comment: That last integral smells like trig substitution.  Try something like $t = r\cos\theta$.

Comment: This is a lot easier [with Pappus Throrem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem), volume=area*length of path of centroid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve $\int_{-r}^r\sqrt{r^2-t^2}dt$, you can use the substitution $t=r\sin\theta$. Then if $t=r$, $\theta=\pi/2$; $t=-r$, $\theta=-\pi/2$. Also, $dt=r\cos\theta d\theta$ and $\sqrt{r^2-t^2}=r\cos\theta$. Hence, we have
$$\int_{-r}^r\sqrt{r^2-t^2}dt=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}r^2\cos^2\theta d\theta
=r^2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^2\theta d\theta.$$
I will leave the remaining part to you.